# IE11 User Agent String breaks <iframe>

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer, iframe, internet-explorer-11

I'm working with a Wordpress site that uses an `iframe` to make an external call to a button that populates on the page and provides a link to the same external site to book appointments.

The iframe works perfectly in all browsers except IE11. The user agent string in IE11 is set to `default`, but if I switch the string in IE's Developer Tools to anything IE10 and down, the button renders and operates perfectly.

**So, does anyone know how to set the user agent string to anything but "default"?** NOTE: This is not the same as setting `User-Agent`, which I've done, and it doesn't work. (or is it? ...and how?)

Example of what I've tried:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10"/>` and variations of this.

**UPDATE:** As an added twist, the `<iframe>` loads in a different `doctype` and `html` declaration. Could this be part of my problem? (I don't have access to the code that's loaded by the `iframe`)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Comment: Stop playing with `X-UA`s, just use a proper HTML5 doctype.

Comment: Already using `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: Please read carefully [Compatibility changes in IE11](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg182625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The conclusion is, that it's useless to downgrade IE11 to IE10. Some legacy functionalities working in IE10 standards have been totatally removed from IE11, and downgrading won't bring them back. The only way is to write your HTML, CSS and scripts in a way which works also in IE11. This is supposed to be quite easy, since there's not much non-standard stuff in IE11.

Comment: Thanks, Teemu. This is very good info, but not yet solving my issue directly as I don't have access to the code that's loaded in by the iframe. Are you thinking I need to send this issue off to the developer, or can I handle this locally?

Comment: You won't loose anything if you report an issue. From the linked MSDN document: "`Starting with IE11, document modes are deprecated and should no longer be used...`".

Comment: My guess is your iframe source is browser sniffing. If you can change the source to not browser sniff but instead feature detect you will be better off.

Comment: It is not the UA string that breaks the iframe, it is the logic in the iframe that is broken, because it relies on UA sniffing instead of feature detection. Your best bet would be to contact the provider of the content that you display in the iframe and ask them to update their code to handle IE11 properly.

Comment: Zlatin - That seems like what I'll have to do. Update your answer to include this and I'll check it as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Please change your detection of IE, to not rely on UA string, but instead use conditional comments and `document.documentMode`

```
var tmp = document.documentMode, e, isIE;

// Try to force this property to be a string. 
try{document.documentMode = "";}
catch(e){ };

// If document.documentMode is a number, then it is a read-only property, and so 
// we have IE 8+.
// Otherwise, if conditional compilation works, then we have IE < 11.
// Otherwise, we have a non-IE browser. 
isIE = typeof document.documentMode == "number" || eval("/*@cc_on!@*/!1");

// Switch back the value to be unobtrusive for non-IE browsers. 
try{document.documentMode = tmp;}
catch(e){ };
```

See http://www.pinlady.net/PluginDetect/IE/

---

Also check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID.userAgent if your code uses this attribute for detection.

---

In short it is not the UA string that breaks the iframe, it is the logic in the iframe that is broken, because it relies on UA sniffing instead of feature detection.

If you do not have control over the content displayed in the iframe, your best bet would be to contact the provider of the content that you display in the iframe and ask them to update their code to handle IE11 properly.

Comment: Zlatin, that seems like a lot of work to simply get the proper UA string reported to the browser. Seems like there should be a simpler method.

Comment: Please read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2013/09/21/internet-explorer-11-user-agent-string-ua-string-sniffing-compatibility-with-gecko-webkit.aspx